Bounds on distance between a point and intersection of convex sets
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two nonempty closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\emptyset \neq X = X_1 \cap X_2$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, can the distance between $x,X$ be bounded by the sum of distances between $x,X_1$ and $x,X_2$. Formally, does there exist a constant $c>0$, such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{equation}
    \text{dist}(x,X) \leq c \left( \text{dist}(x,X_1)+\text{dist}(x,X_2) \right). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where the distance are defined as
\begin{equation}
    \text{dist}(x,X) = \inf\{ \|x-y\|_2:y\in X \}. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
The parameter $c>0$ should depend only on the set $X_1$ and $X_2$.
I can not find any counterexample to the above statement, but i cannot prove it as well.

I think you want $X$ to be non-empty, otherwise the distance of any point to it is $+\infty$ by definition.

Your $X_i$ are probably meant to be non empty as well

Yeah, indeed they should be non-empty.

Let
\begin{align*}
c=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n} \frac{d_X(x)}{d_{X_1}(x)+d_{X_2}(x)}
\end{align*}
Then clearly $d_X(x)\leq c (d_{X_1}(x)+d_{X_2}(x))$ and $c$ is the best such $c$. If in particular $c<\infty$ then the answer to your question is yes.
Let us consider the two lines ($X_1$ and $X_2$) in $\mathbb R^2$ that are the multiples of $(0,1)$ and $(a,1)$ with $a>0$. Their intersection is $X=\{0\}$. Let us consider the sequence of points $x_n=n\left(\frac{a}{2}, 1 \right)$, then $d_{X}(x_n)=\frac{n}{2}\sqrt{a^2+4}$. By symmetry, $d_{X_2}(x_n)=d_{X_1}(x_n)=\| x_n-(0,n) \|=\frac{na}{2}$.
Now
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d_X(x_n)}{d_{X_1}(x_n)+d_{X_2}(x_n)} &= \frac{\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2a}
\end{align*}
As $a\to 0$, this tends to $\infty$, therefore there is no limit to how big $c$ can be.
I believe that as long as $X$ is non-empty, then $c$ should be finite, but cannot prove it yet.

Assuming $X_1,X_2$ are non-empty, i guess. Otherwise your c is not defined

Yes, the $c$ is dependent on $X_1$ and $X_2$, but it may be extremely large.

Define
\begin{align}
X_1 &:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_2 \le 0\}\\
X_2 &:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_2 \ge x_1^2\}.
\end{align}
Then, $X = \{0\}$. Consider the points $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n, 0)$. Then,
\begin{align}
d_X(x_n, y_n) & = 1/n \\
d_{X_1}(x_n, y_n) &= 0 \\
d_{X_2}(x_n, y_n) &\le 1/n^2.
\end{align}
Hence, the desired bound cannot be valid.

thanks a lot. What if the intersection $X$ has non-empty interior ?

I do not know...

@Yunfei If one set intersects the interior of the other, then $c$ exists when $x$ is restricted to bounded sets. If you need it globally, search for "linear regularity".
